# PuppetLabs MYSQL drop database

Tags: mysql, puppet, puppetlabs-mysql

How do you remove a Puppetlabs MYSQL database using this module?

I have tried using the name of the database and ensure => 'absent' but with no luck.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

P.S: I am able to create DBs using this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way of resolving this which is:

```
mysql_database { 'mysql':
  ensure  => 'absent',
  charset => 'latin1',
}
```

Hope this will help :)